# using httpbuilder for grails restful webservice

Tags: web-services, grails, httpbuilder

I am developing a restful webservice using grails for first time and I following the chapter 13 in the grails documentation for setting up a simple response to a GET request.

The thing i do not get is setting up  HTTPBuilder for creating a client which makes a get request. I have downloaded the jar httpbuilder,
The Restful client is defined as follows

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:8080/amazon")

http.request(Method.GET, JSON) { url.path = '/book/list' response.success = { resp, json -> for (book in json.books) { println book.title } } }
```

So the code they have customized for the client is it a new HTTPBuilder class defined ? if yes where do we need to define this class

Right now the routing of URL to show def in my controller is not happeining.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do since I don't know what your localhost service is supposed to return.  Since you're looking for books, here's an example using Google's book search that may be of help.  I wrote so that you can run in the Groovy console if you want, but will work in grails as well.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2' )

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET

def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://www.googleapis.com")

http.handler.failure = { resp, json ->
    println "it broke ${resp} ${json}"
}
http.get(path: '/books/v1/volumes', query:[q:'quilting']) { resp, json ->
    if (resp.status == 200) {
        json?.items.each {book ->
            println "${book?.volumeInfo?.title}"
        }
    } else {
        return [error:"Did not return a proper response: ${resp.status}"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I have really basic question regarding the above code. Is it a class? what file/piece of code is this placed in and where in relation to the project? I have downloaded the HttpBuilder.jar in my lib is that enough?. Sorry I went through the documentation for this but it starts on a level that you know many things..

Comment: ok, looks like you have a loooong way to go.  You should probably go through the grails and groovy documentation a little more thoroughly first.  You can literally copy and paste the code above into the [groovy console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) and it will run (no classes needed).  However, I think you should read a lot more of the documentation first.